# When user unlikes comment all notifications of that user get deleted from database instead of only that specific notification

Tags: java, android, firebase

Have written a new method to delete notifications that a user receives if some other user likes their post, or comments, or likes their comment, etc. The problem is the post notification is being added to the database, but when I for example "unlike" a comment (hitting an ImageView) and then unlike it the notification with it's specific ID aren't deleted from the database and I am not sure why that is. All of the notifications for that user are deleted when I for instance "unlike" a post when only that notification which was sent because I had liked the post should be removed, and the others untouched.

Can someone tell me why this is happening and how to fix it?

[image]

**PostAdapter**

```
holder.like.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if (holder.like.getTag().equals("like")) {
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Likes").child(post.getPostid()).child(mFirebaseUser.getUid()).setValue(true);
                addNotification(post.getPublisher(), post.getPostid());
            } else {
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Likes").child(post.getPostid()).child(mFirebaseUser.getUid()).removeValue();
                deleteNotification(post.getPublisher());
            }
        });

private void deleteNotification(String userId) {
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Notifications");
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Notification notification = snapshot.getValue(Notification.class);
                    if (notification != null) {
                        reference.child(userId).child(notification.getNotificationId()).removeValue();
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As i can see when you use function `addLikeNotification()`, then to `notifid` is assigned last `push()` key. When you try to remove any notification, there is still last value used in `notifid` .

What you can do is to create in your layout new field (per example TextView), set notifid to it and its visibility to `GONE`.

When you try to remove value, firstly assign text from that field to `notifid` and then remove your notification

Comment: Notif in my class is a String value I have it like this in my class ```String notifid = reference.push().getKey();``` I just have it as a global variable. You want me to assign it to a TextView? I am not sure I understand what you mean. Do you mind explaining it a bit more?

Comment: Your variable `String notifid = reference.push().getKey();` is a global variable which is changing every time u use `addLikeNotification()`. Let's say u give 3 likes. Your variable: `notifid = key_value_A`  2nd like: `notifid = key_value_B` third: `notifid = key_value_C`. To remove comment u use same variable (`notifid`). So in this case you will remove them last element only. If you assign somewhere `notifid' you can get this value for a specific notification.
Could you paste your adapter where you define holders?

Comment: Okay man, I just added my Adapter class holders. So I need to add for example a ```TextView``` somewhere in my xml and make it GONE and assign the ```String notifid``` to it in my Adapter class?

Comment: Would try that yes. And everytime you call `holder.comment.setText(comment.getComment())` you should also get `notifid` from database and set it to created textview.

Comment: Bro, I still can't make it work. Why would this TextView help me solve my problem though? If each individual like and notification in general has its own special ID why would I need to set it in a TextView?

Comment: Let's make it another way so you will understand. Please print (`System.out.println()`) your `notifid` in your `addLikeNotification()` function. Then add same line in `holder.commentLike.onClickListener()` before `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Notifications").child(comment.getPublisher()).child(notifid).removeValue();` Then create 3 notifications and try to remove them. Compare results. So compare `notifid` from your notifications with `notifid` you try to remove. Please edit post with result

Comment: Well you're absolutely right. I create three notifications which each had a different ```notified``` value and then when I deleted them (unliked the post) the only one I got back was the last ```notifid``` value... So you're right, but I still don't know how I can fix it.

Comment: I updated the code. I assigned ```mNotificationId``` to a TextView which I set to GONE in my xml. What should I do now? I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Would chat with you to not discuss in comments just don't have enough reputation. Always give full adapter, not only part of it. If you don't get the way i try to explain we can do it in the other way:
Create new Hashmap `HashMap<Int, String> hashMap = new HashMap<>()`
when you create new notification do: `hashMap.put(your_notification_position, notifId)`
In the end when you want to remove notification do `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Notifications").child(post.getPublisher()).child(hashmap.getValue(your_notification_position)).removeValue()`

Comment: Okay so instead of the first method you told me to do use this one, got it. The new ```HashMap``` I create in my ```addLikeNotification();``` method, right? Or in OnCreate?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212543/discussion-between-jmb-and-cyber).

Comment: Bro, you mind if we talk a sec? I can't figure this out